# chapter 7 : :ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: railstutorial.org

I do follow the Hart tutorial and im stuck at the moment.
As far as I know I did everything according to the manual. 
But when I do rspec spec/ I see this error :

```
Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
ActiveModel:
:ForbiddenAttributesError:
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

My code can be found here : https://github.com/roelof1967/sample_app

Roelof

edit 1: thanks, but im on 7.2.2 and there is stated this : With the @user variable so defined, the test for the signup page should be passing again. And there I see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep reading the tutorial, Hartl (with an l) addresses this error in Ch. 7.3.2.

You need to deal with strong parameters, by adding this code to your users controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
end
```

And you need to change one line in your create method in the same controller:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

I hope this helps!